# Powershell Script to delete unused resources in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell

Scenario: People often launch some resources in Azure for testing, and they leave it running after testing. I want to create a Powershell script to identify the resources which has not been used for a long time (Ex-20 days) and delete them.

I was trying to list the resources but was not able to fetch timestamp. I got an etag value which had time in it but in a random order. I was trying to parse that. Is there any better way to achieve this task.

Comment: Can you start by sharing what your draft looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script like this:

To generate the bearer token follow this [blog](https://datathirst.net/blog/2018/9/23/powershell-and-azure-rest-api-authentication)

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "<Subscription_Name>"

$Headers=@{
    'authorization'="Bearer <bearer_token>"
}

# Get all resources and their changed time

$resources= Invoke-RestMethod -uri 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resources?api-version=2018-05-01&$expand=changedTime,createdTime' -method get -Headers $Headers | select-object -Expandproperty value

# Delete all resources which have not been changed since 20 days

foreach ($resource in $resources)
{
$count=0
$time=[datetime]::Parse($resource.changedTime)
$datetime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-20)
$utcDatetime = $datetime.ToUniversalTime()            
if ($time -lt $utcDatetime)
{
$resource.id
$time
Write-Output "Deleting resource now"
Remove-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $resource.id
}
}
```

Hope this helps!